# SVM multiclassification with MATLAB R2015a

Tags: matlab, classification, svm, matlab-guide

I try to use MATLAB R2015a classification toolbox for my 4 classes. I imported my dataset and selected a Gaussian kernel to train my classifier. This is my dataset:

```
my Data=[9.36 0;8.72 0;9.13 0;7.38 0;8.02 0;12.15 1;11.02 1;11.61 1;
12.31 1;15.23 1;52.92 2;54.49 2;48.82 2;52.00 2;49.79 2;22.46 3;30.38 3;
21.98 3;24.46 3;26.08 3];
```

Then I export it into my workspace to use it with my new test data, but when I want to use it in work space this error apears:

> Variables have been created in the base workspace.
>
> To use the exported classifier `trainedClassifier` to make predictions on new data, T, use
>
> `yfit = predict(trainedClassifier, T{:,trainedClassifier.PredictorNames})`
>
> If your new data contains any integer variables, then preprocess the data to doubles like this:
>
> `X = table2array(varfun(@double, T(:,trainedClassifier.PredictorNames)));`
>
> `yfit = predict(trainedClassifier, X)`

I don't understand what does it mean exactly and what is `T` and `yfit`?
How can I test my new data with this classifier?

Comment: Could you please add your code as to how you train the SVM?

Comment: i didn,t right any code.matlab 2015a has some app for classification.you can select your type of classification that i choose gausian kernel svm.then you should import your data that you right it in workspace before.then it has a train button for training and create classifier.when you build this classifier ou can export it to work space easily and use it for new data.it is an app and dosent have any code writing.

Comment: I know you should use `templateSVM`, `fitcecoc` and `predict`. If you actually show the code that built-in GUI creates we can see what you enter in that and try to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: @Adriaan: please read the answers thay i typed below and then help me to solve my problem.h don't have eniugh time to solve it.please help me to write proper code for my classification.thanks.

Comment: Hi, i got an error message like this : Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'cell'.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that you are trying to predict the classes of the data stored in a cell. First import it as a table.
Home_>import_>file name_>import_>(here choose Table from the imported data part). Now you can use your predictor by providing this table name.

Answer (score 0):

yfit= a vector of predicted class labels for predictor data in the table T.

T = Sample data, specified as a table. Each row of T corresponds to one observation, and each column corresponds to one predictor variable. Optionally, T can contain additional columns for the response variable and observation weights. T must contain all of the predictors used to train SVMModel. Multi-column variables and cell arrays other than cell arrays of strings are not allowed.

Test data: example

```
load newdataset
rng(1);
CVSVMModel = fitcsvm(X,Y,'Holdout',0.15,'ClassNames',{'classname1','classname2'},...
'Standardize',true);
CompactSVMModel = CVSVMModel.Trained{1}; % Extract trained, compact classifier
testInds = test(CVSVMModel.Partition);   % Extract the test indices
XTest = X(testInds,:);
predict(CompactSVMModel,XTest);% test here
```

Comment: :what is the X here? please tell me briefly how can i test my new data with this classifier?for example my test data is data1=[9 1;9.36 2;8.74 1;2.56 3;0.11 0] 0,1,2,3 is the 4 classes